# Get data in specific time in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I'm new in Grafana, I'm using Grafana with Prometheus database and I have some problem with it.

I want to get `value at 2300` - `value at 0000`.

But I can't find the way to get value at `2300` and `0000`.

Is there any way to get value at specific time ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> I want to get value at 2300 - value at 0000

If you are trying to get the value `delta` of two point on certain time. You can try `delta` func in PromQL.

For instance, if I want `query_count@1609746000 - query_count@1609742400 (P.S. not a PromQL)`, the time delta is 1hr, so I can do `delta(query_count[1h]@1609746000)`, it will delta the first and the last value between 1609746000-1h ~ 1609746000

Note that [the documentation states](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#delta:%7E:text=delta%20should%20only%20be%20used%20with%20gauges%20and%20native%20histograms)

> delta should only be used with gauges and native histograms