# How to get increase value for a given time range?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I'm using prometheus as grafana's datasoure.
I want to get growth of a `my_metrics`(type `Count`) for a given time range.
For example I can calculate the increase over the last few hours:

```
my_metrics{label="label1"} - my_metrics{label="label1"} offset $__range
```

But how can I calculate the increase for given time range?
For example increase for `2022/05/19 18:00:00` - `2022/05/20 00:00:00`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine [sum](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators) with [rate](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#rate). Rate will be per second, so if you sum up all rate per seconds data points over a given interval you will get the increase over a given time range:

sum by(label) (rate(my_metrics{label="label1"}[time range]))

**Edit:** (delta and some concrete time slot)

It seems as if [the delta function](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#delta) is an easier way to achieve this in the case of gauges.

You will of course get a time series of computed values. To get the value for 2022/05/19 18:00:00 - 2022/05/20 00:00:00 just use an interval of 2h and get the computed value for 2022/05/20 00:00:00 by using a Table.

See [answer of Lentil1016](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72008187/11934850) to a similar question.

Comment: I see...I want the dashboard to dynamically calculate the results based on the time range of grafana. So the formula should like this:
`delta(my_metrics{label="label1"}[${__range}]@${__to:date:seconds})`
Although the metric type is `count` but it is working well

Comment: I think I should use [`increase` function](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase),there are difference between `count` and `guage`: [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59644317/calculate-difference-between-first-and-last-element-in-counter-metrics-range-ve) and [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58674087/why-there-are-both-counters-and-gauges-in-prometheus-if-gauges-can-act-as-counte/58675155#58675155)

Comment: Yes, that is an option. Using increase instead of rate is "syntactic sugar for rate(v) multiplied by the number of seconds" as the [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase) says. Note that you should use sum/rate if you use function [histogram_quantile](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#histogram_quantile).

Answer (score 2):

If you need obtaining the increase of some [counter](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#counter) metric `m` over a time range `(t-d .. t]`, then the following PromQL query can be used:

```
increase(m[d] @ t)
```

If the metric is a [gauge](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#gauge), then just substitute `increase()` with `delta()`:

```
delta(m[d] @ t)
```

These queries use [@ modifier](https://prometheus.io/blog/2021/02/18/introducing-the-@-modifier/) for fixing the end of the time range at `t`. The start of the time range - `t-d` - is adjusted with the `d` lookbehind window in square brackets.

Prometheus provides two endpoints for querying:

- [/api/v1/query](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#instant-query) aka `instant query`. This endpoint accepts the timestamp for the query at `time` argument. So the query can be simplified to just `increase(m[d])` when passed to this endpoint.
- [/api/v1/query_range](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#instant-query) aka `range query`. This endpoint accepts `start` and `end` query args, which specify the time range for the query, alongside `step` query arg, which specifies the interval between returned query results. This endpoint returns independently calculated query results at the following timestamps: `start`, `start+step`, `start+2*step`, ... , `end`. If `increase(m[d])` is passed to this endpoint, then this query is executed independently per each timestamp `t` mentioned above. Grafana queries this endpoint for building graphs. That's why every point on the graph would contain the `m` increase over the lookbehind window `d` ending at this point.

If `m` returns multiple time series, then both `increase(m[d])` and `delta(m[d])` would return individual results per each input time series. These results can be summed by wrapping the query into [sum()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum):

```
sum(increase(m[d]))
```

If you want obtaining the graph, which always starts from zero on the left side and grows with the `m`'s increase over time on the selected time range, then Prometheus doesn't provide such a functionality. But this task can be solved with VictoriaMetrics - this is Prometheus-like monitoring system I work on:

```
running_sum(increase(m))
```

This query uses the following features of VictoriaMetrics:

- `increase()` without lookbehind window in square brackets. VictoriaMetrics automatically sets the lookbehind window to the interval between points shown on the graph in this case. See [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#implicit-query-conversions) for more details.
- [running_sum()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#running_sum) function for calculating the running sum over the per-point `increase()` results on the graph.